Problem with calculating the sum of elements of an n-th order matrix using assembly inline in C++
The problem is that I have a condition where an element should be added to the sum. If the sum of the indices of the element ( j+i>4 ), then add the element to the sum; otherwise, ignore it.
I tried to run it:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int n = 4; 

int main() {
    int A[n][n] = {
        {10000, 2000, 4000, 10000},
        {6000, 1, 1, 1},
        {11000, 1, 1, 1},
        {160000, 1, 1, 1}

    };

    int sum = 0;

    __asm
    {
        mov ecx, 0          

        outer_loop:
        mov ebx, 0          

            inner_loop :
            mov eax, A         
            mov edx, ecx      
            imul edx, n       
            add edx, ebx      

            cmp ecx, 0        
            jle next_column   

            cmp ebx, 0        
            jle next_column   

            mov eax, [A + 4 * edx]  
            add sum, eax            

            next_column :
        inc ebx           
            cmp ebx, n        
            jl inner_loop     

            inc ecx           
            cmp ecx, n        
            jl outer_loop     
    }

    cout << "Sum of elements where i + j > 4: " << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}

Output:
Sum of elements where i + j > 4: 9
What is wrong in my code?

What is i and j ? What result do you expect? 84?

@TedLyngmo "i" and "j" are coordinates of an element in the matrix. "i" is the row number, and "j" is the column number. I expect my code to iterate through the matrix, summing these two coordinates together, and if the sum is greater than 4, then add that element to the total sum.

I want result: 10000+1+1+1+1+1+160000+1+1+1=170008

And that's one of the reasons why you don't use assembler unless you absolutely have to: even the author doesn't understand his own code...

@Swift-FridayPie Could you please fix my code? I've already tried everything I could.

@ChristianStieber as if modern C++ is better

If i is the row and j is the column, what do you mean by "summing these two coordinates together"? Why not write the working algorithm in C++ to start with? It would at least be easier to understand what it is that you want to do.

@BatsamutNikita i can't guarantee result, none of mainstream compilers even support __asm anymore, but I wrote what check should be in theory instead of existing ones.

@TedLyngmo Here is my code only in C++ which do the same: `#include 
using namespace std;
int main() {
const int n = 4;
int A[n][n] = {
{10000, 2000, 4000, 10000},
{6000, 1, 1, 1},
{11000, 1, 1, 1},
{160000, 1, 1, 1}
};
double sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        if (j + i > 4) {
            sum += A[i-1][j-1];
        }
    }
}

cout << "Sum of elements where i + j >= 4: " << sum << endl;

return 0;

}`

Comments are not the place for code samples -- [edit] your question and place the code there.

@BatsamutNikita Ok, that wasn't easy to understand from the explanation in the question. Especially since arrays are zero-based in C++ so one would expect i and j to go from 0 to 3, but then the check would be > 2 instead, like this:  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { if (j + i > 2) { sum += A[i][j]; } } }

A comparison is not even required. The triangular pattern can be driven from the j-loop's starting value: https://godbolt.org/z/znEos74x1

Elephant in the room: Why are we writing inline assembly for a loop and sum? Just write C++ and it’ll produce code that is orders of magnitude better than any assembly you can produce...

@Dúthomhas because it's a very tiny elephant. I'm prtty sure that compiler would turn it into much tighter loop even..alright, it actually just used MMX instructions and no loop at all.

@Swift-FridayPie The elephant is bigger than the room we’re in. Inline assembly just makes code non-portable, more difficult to maintain, and harder to understand. If there are concrete, demonstrable reasons for using assembly, there is that, but this example is kind of the poster boy for not using it.

it's because its size was treated as signed. Yeah, I totally agree. THe only reason might be educational. I'm not even sure what compiler uses these mnemonics still for inline. It used to be Borland style, but did Borland  had imul?

@Dúthomhas I saw practical reasons for assembler learning: various codecs and signal processing. That is optimized to a tee in a way compiler will never do, but in that area the classic i386 instructions are useless.

@BatsamutNikita I've already tried everything I could. -- Did you try godbolt?  You just enter the working C++ code on the left window pane, and on the right window pane is the assembly language.  Even then, using a good debugger that shows the mix of source and assembly (like the Visual Studio debugger for example), you get the assembly code.  Questions asking for what assembly code needs to be done for C++ code is answered by using the tools available to you -- no one needs to guess.

I'll go extremely functional with this: auto sum = std::ranges::fold_left_first(A | std::views::join, std::plus<>{}); a one linear with vivid intent and minimum room for bugs.

I'll be a little disassembler here:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int n = 4; 

int main() {
    int A[n][n] = {
        {10000, 2000, 4000, 10000},
        {6000, 1, 1, 1},
        {11000, 1, 1, 1},
        {160000, 1, 1, 1}

    };

    int sum = 0;

    for(int ecx = 0; ecx < n; ++ecx )
       for(int ebx = 0; ebx < n; ++ebx ) {
          int edx =  ecx*n + ebx;
          if(ecx <= 0) continue; 
          if(ebx <= 0) continue;
          sum += *(&(A[0][0]) + edx);
    }

    cout << "Sum of elements where i + j > 4: " << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}

It just excludes first column and first row, and you get the right answer for that case - 9.
What actually should be in loop:
   for(int ecx = 0; ecx < n; ++ecx )
       for(int ebx = 0; ebx < n; ++ebx ) {
          int edx =  ecx + ebx;
          if(edx <= 4) continue; 

          edx += ecx*n + ebx;
          sum += *(&(A[0][0]) + edx);
    }

Or in asm (kind of, not tested, could be written better):
__asm
    {
        mov ecx, 0          

        outer_loop:
        mov ebx, 0          

            inner_loop :      
            mov edx, ecx 
            add edx, ebx     

            cmp edx, 4              
            jle next_column   
         
            mov edx, ecx      
            imul edx, n       
            add edx, ebx   

            mov eax, [A + 4 * edx]  
            add sum, eax            

            next_column :
        inc ebx           
            cmp ebx, n        
            jl inner_loop     

            inc ecx           
            cmp ecx, n        
            jl outer_loop     
    }

The problem is it's array indice are 0 based, so in this case correct result is 3, not 170008. You should account for that. Comparison should be  cmp edx, 2 i.e. i + j < 2.
PS: My understanding is that mov eax, A at loop beginning in original code doesn't do anything at all. eax could be used instead of edx at that point.
